# AngularJS preselect an option with the data recived from the server

Tags: angularjs

I have created CRUD with AngularJS, in the update part when it comes to selecting, I am unable to get a preselected value. Text fields show the correct data and I am able to update all fields without error. Please understand I am a beginner. The code pasted below are pieces that are important nothing else. And thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div ng-init="readLangs()" class="md-block">
    <select 
        ng-model="lang_id" 
        ng-options="lang.lang_name for lang in langs">
    </select>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.showUpdateChnForm = function(chn_id){

// get chn to be edited
chnsFactory.readOneChn(chn_id).then(function successCallback(response){

    // put the values in form
    $scope.chn_id = response.data.chn_id;
    $scope.chn_name = response.data.chn_name;
    $scope.chn_price = response.data.chn_price;
    $scope.lang_id = response.data.lang_id;
    }
}
```

The readOneChn will output the lang_id and lang_name

```
{
"chn_id":"2",
"chn_name":"BBC World News",
"chn_price":"1.00",
"lang_id":"1",
"lang_name":"English"
}
```

The select options are retrived from server
JS

```
$scope.readLangs = function(){
// use chns factory
chnsFactory.readLangs().then(function successCallback(response){
    $scope.langs = response.data.records;
}, function errorCallback(response){
    $scope.showToast("Unable to read record.");
});
}
```

Comment: does your showUpdateChnForm function gets executed somewhere ?

Comment: I cut the code down when posting here, the code is not complete. The same function also opens up a Dialog. The Dailog contains the form and update button. The update button function updates the values in server. The values are being updated properly.

Comment: Does $scope.langs contains objects which have lang_id property ? if so, i think you should change your ng-options directive like this :

ng-options="lang.lang_id as lang.lang_name for lang in langs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  [@Anurag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7867822/anurag-srivastava) I have solved the problem.
I changed the `ng-model` as you said to `lang`, but there is no need for a filter. There needs to be a `track by`. I remember from another solution asking to use `track by` but it never worked for me. Due to [@Anurag's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55019119/5535245), I learned to do this `$scope.lang = {lang_id: response.data.lang_id}` and now If I added `track by lang.lang_id` and it works.

HTML

```
<div ng-init="readLangs()" class="md-block">
    <select ng-model="lang"
            ng-options="lang.lang_name for lang in langs track by lang.lang_id">    
    </select>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.showUpdateChnForm = function(chn_id){
    // get chn to be edited
    chnsFactory.readOneChn(chn_id).then(function successCallback(response){
        // put the values in form

        $scope.chn_id = response.data.chn_id;
        $scope.chn_name = response.data.chn_name;
        $scope.chn_price = response.data.chn_price;
        $scope.lang = {lang_id: response.data.lang_id};
    }
}
```